# Can a ExtJS Proxy actively notify it's Stores of changes?

Tags: extjs

As far as I can see, a `Ext.data.proxy.Proxy` is connected to a `Ext.data.store.Store` always by the `Store` calling into the `Proxy` for CRUD operations.

Is the reverse direction also possible? That is having the `Proxy` actively notifiy the `Store` of changes to the remote data represented by the `Proxy`?

For example: another user modifies the backend data. The backend notifies all connected users of the change. The change is mediated by the `Proxy` to the `Store` and then i.e. a grid using the `Store` immediately shows up the changed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly how it works! The proxy makes a request and whenever it gets the response it notify to the store and the store does the same with the grid.

However, the application model that you are talking about is known as [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling) and it requires a diferent kind of proxy that extjs doesn´t have. Anyway do it is quite simple reading the streamed request and filling the store for yourself (sounds hard but it isn´t)

You can take a look at [this](http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/websync/demos/extjsticker) example (run it and see the source code please)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I am using WebSocket (not Comet hacks) .. to be specific, PubSub over WebSocket (using AutobahnJS and WAMP). In the meantime, I have moved on to Knockout.js with it's MVVM model being much more convenient and a better fit to Autobahn.